# when two sets of vectors have the same all linear combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to solve this kind of question this is my issue firstly I'm given tow sets of vectors S,T

S={v1,v2,v3,v4} this one is dependent 
T={v1,v2,v4} this one is independent 
as you may notice the set T is a subset of S which has the same vectors except {v3} then how to show that the two sets have the same all linear combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just have to show that $v_3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, v_4$.

Hence adding $v_3$ doesn't change the span.

Comment: sorry, sir could you please explain what does it mean when two sets of vectors have the same all linear combinations?

Comment: If we let $A = span\{ v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ and $B = span\{ v_1, v_2,  v_4\}$. Then the two sets $A$ and $B$ are the same.

Comment: thank you, sir, you are really great